# AppScripts Function returning NaN

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on an automated ELO System in Google Sheets, and I have an issue with my AppScripts, in which the Formula which outputs a new ELO is for some reason returning NaN. Each individual value that goes into the formula is a number, so I was wondering what the issue is with my function?

Here is my code:

```
function Loop() {
    const Sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3Test');

    var EndRow = Sheet2.getLastRow();

    for (var i = 2; i <= EndRow; i++) {
        Utilities.sleep(12)
        var Team1ELO = Sheet2.getRange(i, 10).getValue()
        var Team2ELO = Sheet2.getRange(i, 11).getValue()
        var ExpectedResult = Sheet2.getRange(i, 12).getValue()
        var ActualResult = Sheet2.getRange(i, 13).getValue()
        var KFact = Sheet2.getRange(i, 14).getValue()



        var newELOVal = Sheet2.getRange(i, 8).getValue()
        var newELOVal2 = Sheet2.getRange(i, 9).getValue()

        if (newELOVal == "" & newELOVal2 == "" && Team1ELO != "" && Team2ELO != "" && KFact != "" && ActualResult != "" != ExpectedResult != "") {

            var TeamAELOOutput = Team1ELO + KFact * (ActualResult - ExpectedResult)

            var TeamBELOOutput = (Team2ELO + (KFact * ((1 - ActualResult) - (1 - ExpectedResult))))

            Sheet2.getRange(i, 8).setValue(TeamAELOOutput)
            Sheet2.getRange(i, 9).setValue(TeamBELOOutput)


        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my sloppy code by the way, I just started using Sheets + AppScripts 2 days ago.

Comment: `&` is not the same as `&&`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. However, for some reason, it still returns NAN. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: A `NaN` value will propagate through arithmetic expressions. What's happening is that *something* in your calculations is `NaN` (perhaps starting off as `undefined` or a non-numeric string) and that's giving you an overall result of `NaN`. You'll have to debug the problem step by step to see what value is unexpectedly not a number.

Comment: This is also incorrect (probably): `ActualResult != "" != ExpectedResult != ""`

Comment: I've already ensured that each component of my calculation is a number. I'll make sure to double check but I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: I also already fixed that issue when fixing the first bug, and I also just double checked that every value on its own returns a number

Comment: I've been able to narrow it down slightly and it turns out that the values that return NaN is this specific expression (ActualResult - ExpectedResult)

Comment: So what are the values of ActualResult and ExpectedResult in that circumstance?  Maybe output those values to the sheet instead of TeamAELOOutput etc, to see where it's failing.

Comment: I already made sure to output those values to the sheets individually to which it replied as numbers. Does Appscripts support arithmetic with fractions?

Comment: You mean with decimal such as `1.25`?  Or do you mean `1 1/4`?

Comment: Not mixed numbers, just fractions such as 91/128

Comment: `"91/128"` is not a number.

Comment: Yes it is, it's an expression equal to 91 divided by 128

Comment: You cannot use that as part of a JavaScript arithmetic expression. You could evaluate it and turn it into a number.

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the issue with the code using the Eval function. Works fine now, thanks!